# World of Tanks on Chrome OS

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to know whether the online game World of Tanks can be played on a Chromebook.

Is that on topic over here or should I ask that on Super User?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While *in general* questions about things like the technical system requirements of a game are on topic, *in this specific case*, I feel obliged to warn you that such a question will be **heavily** downvoted, and perhaps voted as NARQ, because the answer is trivial to acquire from even a cursory glance at the World of Tanks website.

([The answer is no. World of Tanks requires Windows.](http://worldoftanks.com/game/guide/en/general/frequently_asked_questions#a2))

Comment: In addition, we don't allow questions of, "Will game X run on system with specs Y?".  Those are too localized to be of use to anyone except those with your exact configuration.

Comment: @fbueckert I know, old question. Still: That wouldn't be localized, as he's most likely not the only one with a Chromebook. It *would* be localized if it was `Will World of Tanks run on Mac OS with Netscape Navigator and a GeForce 892 v2 with 49.5MB RAM`

Comment: @IanCarroll That doesn't matter.  The reason why we have a blanket ban on these types of questions is that the chances of it helping anyone else is astoundingly low.  There are at *least* three different Chromebooks, which means they are no different than any other system.

Comment: @fbueckert They all auto-update. They all run the same arch. They all run the same OS.

Comment: @IanCarroll They still run different hardware.  You may have a point if each and everyone one of them works *exactly* the same as the others, with no inherent quirks unique to each system.  I don't think there's a way to guarantee that, though.

Comment: @IanCarroll If you want an exception to the ban, I encourage you to make your own meta post.  Either way, we've hijacked this one enough.

Answer (score 2):

That question is off-topic in Super User.

From [Super User's FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question …
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> **video games** or consoles

If it was asked in Arqade, it may be downvoted, but I don't think it should be closed as NARQ (not a real question) or off-topic as per:

- [What's the policy regarding "easy" questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/559/4797)
- [Is it acceptable to cast a close vote if one thinks that a question is 'General Reference' (e.g. the answer is already indexed in a community wiki)?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5376/4797)
- [Should we care if an answer is from Googled information, as long as it is right?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3898/4797)
- [Do we need a "General Reference" close reason?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3978/4797)

Comment: Maybe not NARQ, but definitely off-topic.

Comment: "*...definitely off-topic*" You mean in SU or in Arqade? If it's the latter, care to expound?

Comment: I did.  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/world-of-tanks-on-chrome-os/7178?noredirect=1#comment19606_7176

Comment: @fbueckert You mean it should be closed as 'Too Localized' (*not* as 'off-topic')?

Comment: Either would work; they're both valid.

Comment: @fbueckert Care to expound on how it is off-topic? The comment of yours you linked to explains how you think it is 'Too Localized' (not as off-topic).

Comment: These types of questions hit one of the blanket bans (that of asking if a system can run a game), which is why it would be off topic.  It's not salvagable by any means.